# Google App Engine return object with reference set

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Hi I am kind of trying to get the concept behind DataStore as a No-SQL database, what I am trying to fetch is a list of object wich have been "reference" by another. As this

```
class Person(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)

class Contact(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    email = db.StringProperty()
    trader = db.ReferenceProperty(Person)
```

This works fine and they get to be saved when I use person.put() without any problem. But when I try to retrieve it and encoded as json it nevers shows me the **contact** as a list in fact it totally ignores it.

```
    persons_query = Person.all()
    persons = persons_query.fetch(50)
    data = json.encode(persons)
```

I would expect person to have a collection of Contact but it doesn't any ideas on how to solve this problem?

To make it clearer currently i am getting something like this:

```
[
 {
  name: "John Doe"
 }
]
```

I would like to be

```
[
 {
  name: "John Doe"
  contacts: [{name:"Alex", email:'alex@gmail.com'}]
 }
]
```

**Edit**

Thanks all you were right I needed to fetch the collection of contacts there was only one issue for this is that when Contact was being encoded it recursively tried to encode the Trader object and this it's contact and so on.

So I got an obvious error recursive error,  the solution to this was clearly to remove the trader object from the Contact when it's being encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a custom toJson function in your class

```
class Person(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)

    def toJson(self):
        contact = self.contact_set #this is the default collection name for your class
        d = {"name":self.name,"contact":contact}
        return json.dumps(d)

class Contact(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    email = db.StringProperty()
    trader = db.ReferenceProperty(Person)
```

then you may do the ff:

```
persons_query = Person.all()
persons = persons_query.fetch(50)
data = person.toJson()
```

Answer (score 1):

To fetch all the contacts you will need to write a custom json encoder, which fetches all of the reverse of the reference property.

ReferenceProperties automatically get a reverse query.  From the docs "collection_name is the name of the property to give to the referenced model class. The value of the property is a Query for all entities that reference the entity. If no collection_name is set, then modelname_set (with the name of the referenced model in lowercase letters and _set added) is used."

So you would add a method to resolve the reverse reference set query.

```
class Person(db.Model):
   name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
   def contacts(self):
       return self.contact_set.fetch(50)  # should be smarter than that
```

Then use it in your custom json encoder.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all the contacts that include a person you will need to issue a query for it.

```
contacts = Contact.all().filter("trader =", person)
```

Comment: what if I want to retrieve all the persons and his contacts in the same object?

Comment: You'd have to denormalize and store a copy of the contacts within the Person object.  This may be a good way to go if you query the Person often, since it saves you from having to query the Contacts.  However, it'll then also be up to you to keep the data synchronized with the actual contacts.  Or if you don't mind doing the extra query, you can just merge the two into a dictionary and run that through the json encoder.